# SQL Query to Sum Amounts Based on LINK_CUST_TRX_ID and LINE_TYPE

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, group

I have a SQL database table with the following structure:

| TRX_NO | CUST_TRX_ID | EXT_AMT | LINE_TYPE | LINK_CUST_TRX_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 320 | 36 | 155 | LINE |  |
| 320 | 50 | 9.3 | TAX | 36 |
| 320 | 51 | 59.52 | TAX | 45 |
| 320 | 45 | 992 | LINE |  |

The "TRX_NO" column represents transaction numbers, "CUST_TRX_ID" is the customer transaction ID, "EXT_AMT" is the extended amount, "LINE_TYPE" indicates whether it's a "LINE" or "TAX" type, and "LINK_CUST_TRX_ID" links "TAX" rows to their corresponding "LINE" rows.

I've attempted to write an SQL query to calculate the sum of 'EXT_AMT' for each 'TRX_NO,' but I'm having trouble combining 'TAX' type amounts with their corresponding 'LINE' type amounts. Here's what I've tried so far

```
WITH combined AS (
  SELECT TRX_NO, EXT_AMT
  FROM your_table
  WHERE LINE_TYPE = 'LINE'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.TRX_NO, t1.EXT_AMT + COALESCE(SUM(t2.EXT_AMT), 0) AS EXT_AMT
  FROM your_table t1
  LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.LINK_CUST_TRX_ID = t2.CUST_TRX_ID
  WHERE t1.LINE_TYPE = 'TAX'
  GROUP BY t1.TRX_NO, t1.CUST_TRX_ID, t1.EXT_AMT
)
SELECT TRX_NO, SUM(EXT_AMT) AS EXT_AMT
FROM combined
GROUP BY TRX_NO
ORDER BY TRX_NO;
```

I need to write an SQL query that calculates the sum of "EXT_AMT" for each "TRX_NO," taking into account the "LINE_TYPE." Specifically, I want to combine "TAX" type amounts with their corresponding "LINE" type amounts and calculate the total for each "TRX_NO." The desired output should look like this:

| TRX_NO | EXT_AMT |
| --- | --- |
| 320 | 155.00 |
| 320 | 992.00 |
| 320 | 68.82 |

I'm looking for an SQL query that can achieve this result. Any assistance or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you make a mistake when providing the sample data and the expected result? Your sample data has two different LINE_TYPES only, but your result has three different rows. Why that?

Comment: if you see last result that is cumulative of tax line. so tahts way result is expected

Comment: So your goal is to sum all rows with Line Type = Tax in one single row and keep all other rows separated?

Comment: yes @JonasMetzler

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do 2 queries and do union

SELECT TRX_NO, SUM(EXT_AMT) FROM transactions
where LINE_TYPE != 'LINE'
group by TRX_NO
UNION
SELECT TRX_NO, EXT_AMT FROM (
SELECT TRX_NO, CUST_TRX_ID, SUM(EXT_AMT)  EXT_AMT FROM transactions
where LINE_TYPE = 'LINE'
group by TRX_NO, CUST_TRX_ID
) A

Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can write two queries, one for all rows with `LINE_TYPE = TAX` and one for all others. They can be put in one result using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
  TRX_NO, EXT_AMT
FROM transactions
WHERE LINE_TYPE <> 'TAX'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  TRX_NO, SUM(EXT_AMT)
FROM transactions
WHERE LINE_TYPE = 'TAX'
GROUP BY TRX_NO
ORDER BY TRX_NO;
```

Don't forget the `GROUP BY` clause in the second query! Since you want to sum the rows with this line_type, you need to group by `TRX_NO`.

Try out above query on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hH1djIt1).

It's based on your sample data, but additionally includes some rows with another `TRX_NO`.